# Resources.getSystem().openRawResource gives resource not found exception

Tags: android, inputstream, static-methods

In my android app I want to access my text file in static method but using this code:

`InputStream is = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.adv_types);`

gives me run time exception: resource Not Found Exception

while I can use this code to access the file in non static method:

`InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.adv_types);`

though its not usable in static method.

Do you have any idea why the first code does not work?
And what is the solution to access text file (or resources in general) in static method?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.1_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java. and this 
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/content/ContextWrapper.java

Answer (score 6):

because `Resources.getSystem()` give you access only to the system resources not to the application resources. From the documentation:

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only
>   system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for
>   the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based
>   on orientation, etc).

Comment: Do you mean for `Resources.getSystem()`?  `getResources()` uses the current Context.

Comment: exactly. getResource() is a method of the Context class

Comment: I mean I think you labeled it wrong.  What you posted is the Javadoc for `Resources.getSystem()`.

Comment: you can not. You need to have a context